# How to find duplicate values in different object fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How can I search with `mongoose` to find duplicate values in different fields?

**Here is sample document:**

```
{
 "followers": {
               {
                "_id": "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75a9f4"
               },
               {
                "_id": "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75a8c3"
               }
              },
 "following": {
               {
                "_id": "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75a9f4"
               },
               {
                "_id": "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75b7a2"
               }
              },
}
```

I want to find same `_id` values under `followers` and `following` fields.

**Expected Output:**

```
{
 {
  "_id": "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75a9f4"
 }
}
```

What query should I use?

Comment: `followers` and `following` would be the Array. right?

Comment: @HardikShah yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with this:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$followers"},
    { $unwind : "$following"},
    { $project : {
        _id: 0,
        matchId: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ "$followers._id", "$following._id" ]} ,
          "$following._id", null ] }
    }},
    {$match : {"matchId" : {$ne : null}}}
])
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "matchId" : "5bf6d610d3a3f31a6c75a9f4"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but How I can query within a single document( I want to find duplicate ids in a single document but in two different fields)

Comment: Yes,  you can with the same snippet I have provided. Just to add `$match` to specific Id at the top level of aggregation. Can you post your whole sample data struct? So, I can modify with your requirement.